# How to make case statement match a number range?

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I'm running a switch case with column numbers which can be in the range 0 - 50. Now each case supports discrete column number and I observe its failure.

Here is the code:

```
    i=10
    a=1
    b=0.65
    if [ "$a" != "$b" ]; then 
       case $i in  
            [1]|[2]|[5]) echo "Not OK"; ;; 
            [9-10]|[12]) echo "may be ok"; ;; 
            *) echo "no clue - $i"; ;; 
       esac
   fi
```

I expect this code to output `may be ok` but get `no clue - 10`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Bash `case` doesn't work with numbers ranges. `[]` is for shell patterns.

for instance this case `[1-3]5|6)` will work for 15 or 25 or 35 or 6.

Your code should look like this:

```
i=10
a=1
b=0.65
if [ "$a" != "$b" ] ; then
   case $i in
        1|2|5) echo "Not OK"; ;;
        9|10|12) echo "may be ok"; ;;
        *) echo "no clue - $i"; ;;
   esac;
fi
```

If `i` can be `real` **between** 9 and 10 then you'll need to use `if` (instead of case) with ranges.

Comment: used if statements to group columns for switch case. That way it's readable. Will there be performance impact, as records are in millions? Example: if [[ ("$i" -ge "1" && "$i" -le "5") || ("$i" -eq "8") || ("$i" -eq "9") ]] ; then
                        caseId=1
                   elif ....

Comment: There is a slight impact. I timed the `if` statement you wrote in your comment between 1..1000000 (incrementing variables in the loop) and it took about 22 seconds. running a 'similar' case (matching 7 integers on first case and * on the second) and it took 16 seconds. I think it's not all that bad - the difference for million iterations being roughly 6 seconds.

Comment: e.g. for parsing cmd line args -h or -? or --help '''-[h\?]|--help'''.

Answer (score 5):

**`if` and `[` solution**

```
arg=1
if [ "$arg" -lt 5 ]; then
  echo 'less than 5'
elif [ "$arg" -lt 15 ]; then
  echo 'less than 15'
elif [ "$arg" -eq 17 ] || [ "$arg" -eq 19 ]; then
  echo '17 or 19'
else
  echo 'neither'
fi
```

**POSIX 7**

Bash follows POSIX as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482040/895245

Here is the quote: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01 section "Case Conditional Construct":

> The conditional construct case shall execute the compound-list corresponding to the first one of several patterns (see Pattern Matching Notation) [...] Multiple patterns with the same compound-list shall be delimited by the '|' symbol. [...]
>
> The format for the case construct is as follows:
>
> ```
> case word in
>      [(] pattern1 ) compound-list ;;
>      [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list ;;] ...
>      [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
>   esac
> ```

and then http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13 section "2.13. Pattern Matching Notation" says:

> [ If an open bracket introduces a bracket expression as in XBD RE Bracket Expression

and [extended regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) points to section "9.3.5 RE Bracket Expression" which says:

> A bracket expression (an expression enclosed in square brackets, "[]" ) is an RE that shall match a specific set of single characters, and may match a specific set of multi-character collating elements, based on the non-empty set of list expressions contained in the bracket expression.

So only individual characters are considered when you do something like:

```
[9-10]
```