# How do I exclude certain cases in a switch case statement?

Tags: bash, shell, case-statement

```
option="${1}"
        case ${option} in
                1) do A
                   do B 
        ;;
                2) do A
                   do B
                   do C 
                ;;
        3) do A
           do B
           do C
        ;;
        esac
```

Above, I am repeating 'do C' for case 2 & 3. Instead of this redundancy, is there a way I can define a case that applies to all cases, except case 1 or a case which applies to case 2,3,5) (basically whichever case I want)
like:
`allExceptCase1)` OR `Only2,3,5AndNotTheOthers)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every option in a `case` statement is separate, but they are defined by shell *patterns*.  Thus you could do this:

```
case ${option} in
  1) do A
     do B 
  ;;
  [23])
     do A
     do B
     do C 
  ;;
esac
```

You can nest case statements, too, so you could also do this:

```
case ${option} in
  [123])
    do A
    do B 
    case ${option} in
      [23]) do C 
      ;;
    esac
  ;;
esac
```

If you were willing to assume that `${option}` would always be either `1`, `2`, or `3`, then you could also do this:

```
do A
do B 
case ${option} in
  [23])
     do C 
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you! The nesting option is particularly helpful, because each of my cases have a few unique statements and a few common statements.

Answer (score 2):

Here I've covered one case with two values and another "default" clause.

```
case ${option} in
  1) do A
     do B 
     ;;
  2|3) do A
       do B
       do C 
      ;;
   *) do D
      ;;
esac
```

RTFM: (http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)

[Stack: bash switch case matching multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482040/600360)